# Assignments on Javascript for beginners?

Tags: javascript

Can you suggest some good **Javascript assignments/homework** to **C programmers**, who are not  familiar with Javascript?

They are strong in C, hence basic Javascript.

I need few JS related assignments which I can assign to them, to help them understand **Web-Dev** and **Prototype** concepts.

I'm not looking for the tutorials which they need to refer.

I think this question is little different from the question
[What’s the best way to introduce non-majors to HTML / programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118755/whats-the-best-way-to-introduce-non-majors-to-html-programming)

Comment: http://www.webtrainingcentre.com/javascript-assignments/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JavaScript Assignments](http://www.webhammer.com/javascript/exercises/index.html)

[JavaScript homeworks](http://www.wn.ro/js/homework1.html)

Comment: Sadly, `JavaScript homeworks` seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest differences between JavaScript and C is how scope is defined.  In C closures are a convenience that are of little importance.  In JavaScript closures are incredibly powerful.

My suggestion to use is to attempt to write a program in JavaScript using what you know of C.  Make the program as object oriented as absolutely possible.  Always define your variables at the top of a function using a single var command.  You will see the differences pretty quickly.  It is important that always define your variables for them to have scope otherwise they are accidental globals.

Try to write an application that takes information from a page and sorts it alphabetically and returns a response that is configurable based upon arguments supplied to the root function.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/JS/default.asp
I would proceed to w3schools, and learn from it.

Comment: I wouldn't, for reasons outlined here: http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score -1):

If I were you I'd familiarize myself with the jQuery framework - http://jquery.com/

There are lots of tutorials there, it's a lot easier and more powerful than attempting to write straight javascript if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: I'd say the opposite: Don't use jQuery until you understand straight Javascript. Only understanding the abstraction doesn't help.

Comment: jquery is quited advanced framework with namespaces, prototypes concepts